# Non-virtual methods in abstract base class

Tags: polymorphism

I'm trying to write a simple chess game, which is primarily an exercise for polymorphism. I'm supposed to create an abstract class *chessmen* and inherit from it the chess pieces. Now, I decided that for every piece, there should be some methods (non-virtual) like *getColor()* and *getRank()* which do essentially the same thing, so I thought it would be more convenient to have such methods in the base *chessmen* class to do the job. But I wasn't sure if there is a way to do that correctly. I wrote some simple test code to see if it works and it compiled without a problem, but the output was definitely not right.

So I'm asking, is there a way to do that?

Edit: My test.cpp code

```
class Dad
{
    public:
            virtual void Void() =0;
            bool  biT;
            bool getBit(){return biT;}
};

class Kid: public Dad
{
    public:
        void Void(){}
};

int main()
{
    Dad* dP = new Kid;
    cout<<dP->getBit();
}
```

and the output is something like 197, not a bool.

Comment: Post the code, what went wrong, and why you think it should have gone differently.

Comment: My magic ball is broken today, so you should share with us the problematic piece of source code.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please post your code that cause problems.

Comment: Well I thought what I was trying to do was the problem, not my code. And I still think it is. I hope I've explained clear enough what I wanted to do.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore I did that.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C++: referencing uninitialized values causes undefined behavior. `biT` is not initialized before being referenced. One possible way to do so would be to tell the object what color you want it to be at creation. Also, you're eventually going to want to `delete` that object you created with `new`, but doing so will also invoke undefined behavior since you haven't defined a `virtual` destructor in the base class.

```
class Dad
{
    public:
            Dad(bool b) : biT(b) {}
            virtual ~Dad() {}
            virtual void Void() =0;
            bool  biT;
            bool getBit(){return biT;}
};

class Kid: public Dad
{
    public:
        Kid(bool b) : Dad(b) {}
        void Void(){}
};

int main()
{
    Dad* dP = new Kid(false);
    cout<<dP->getBit();
    delete dP;
}
```

Comment: That means even a bool type can be returned as not a bool? How can that be? I expected to get either a 1 or a 0. Thanks you very much.

Comment: Yes - undefined behavior means the program is allowed to do *anything*, as far as the standard is concerned. It could light your computer on fire and that would be just peachy.